# Tablesorter ignore some data in div

Tags: javascript, jquery, tablesorter

i need to sort number in table with the original tablesorter.

My problem is :
In my table, i've a TD i would like to sort out, but in this TD, i've some DIV like in this jsfiddle :

http://jsfiddle.net/2mzj57jt/1/

```js
$(function() {
  $.tablesorter.addParser({
    id: 'colpap',
    is: function(s) {
      return false;
    },
    format: function(s) {
      var number = parseFloat(s.replace(/\s+/g, ''));
      return isNaN(number) ? s : number;
    },
    type: 'numeric'
  });
  $('table').tablesorter({
    theme: 'blue',
    headers: {
      0: {
        sorter: 'colpap'
      }
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<table class="tablesorter">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Value</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>256 236
        <div class="info" style="background-color: rgb(166, 194, 255);">6 236</div>
        <div class="info" style="background-color: rgb(166, 194, 255);">5 000</div>
        <div class="info" style="background-color: rgb(166, 194, 255);">11 253</div>
        <div class="info" style="background-color: rgb(166, 194, 255);">233 747</div>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>11 256 232
        <div class="info" style="background-color: rgb(166, 194, 255);">4 253 620</div>
        <div class="info" style="background-color: rgb(166, 194, 255);">3 501 306</div>
        <div class="info" style="background-color: rgb(166, 194, 255);">3 501 306</div>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>23 056
        <div class="info" style="background-color: rgb(166, 194, 255);">20 000</div>
        <div class="info" style="background-color: rgb(166, 194, 255);">3 056</div>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>11 536
        <div class="info" style="background-color: rgb(166, 194, 255);">1 536</div>
        <div class="info" style="background-color: rgb(166, 194, 255);">2 500</div>
        <div class="info" style="background-color: rgb(166, 194, 255);">7 500</div>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>1 023 585
        <div class="info" style="background-color: rgb(166, 194, 255);">1 023 585</div>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

We see gender does not work because DIV parasite sorting !
I think that would just ignore the DIV worked sorting

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To ignore other data you need to take only first line in your formatter:

```
var number = parseFloat(s.split('\n')[0].replace(/\s+/g, ''));
```

Full code at **[Updated Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/2mzj57jt/2/)**.

Detailed below:

```js
$(function() {
  $.tablesorter.addParser({
    id: 'colpap',
    is: function(s) {
      return false;
    },
    format: function(s) {
      var number = parseFloat(s.split('\n')[0].replace(/\s+/g, ''));
      return isNaN(number) ? s : number;
    },
    type: 'numeric'
  });
  $('table').tablesorter({
    theme: 'blue',
    headers: {
      0: {
        sorter: 'colpap'
      }
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://tablesorter.com/__jquery.tablesorter.min.js"></script>
<link href="http://tablesorter.com/themes/blue/style.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<table class="tablesorter">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Value</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>256 236
        <div class="info" style="background-color: rgb(166, 194, 255);">6 236</div>
        <div class="info" style="background-color: rgb(166, 194, 255);">5 000</div>
        <div class="info" style="background-color: rgb(166, 194, 255);">11 253</div>
        <div class="info" style="background-color: rgb(166, 194, 255);">233 747</div>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>11 256 232
        <div class="info" style="background-color: rgb(166, 194, 255);">4 253 620</div>
        <div class="info" style="background-color: rgb(166, 194, 255);">3 501 306</div>
        <div class="info" style="background-color: rgb(166, 194, 255);">3 501 306</div>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>23 056
        <div class="info" style="background-color: rgb(166, 194, 255);">20 000</div>
        <div class="info" style="background-color: rgb(166, 194, 255);">3 056</div>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>11 536
        <div class="info" style="background-color: rgb(166, 194, 255);">1 536</div>
        <div class="info" style="background-color: rgb(166, 194, 255);">2 500</div>
        <div class="info" style="background-color: rgb(166, 194, 255);">7 500</div>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>1 023 585
        <div class="info" style="background-color: rgb(166, 194, 255);">1 023 585</div>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Thank, that work on fiddle, but on my programm not :/  
Do you think is because div are generate by PHP code ?

Comment: Before this splitting of line, try to `console.log(s)` and check what text you are dealing with. Maybe try to add new line in PHP before DIVs: `"\n"` (using double quotes).

Comment: The new line "\n" doesn't work. And my console.log(s); output the contents of the div :/

Comment: It should output total, than DIV contents in other line(s).

Comment: Sorry, i would say : my console.log output the total number of the TD, DIV include. Exemple the first line on my program : output : 256 236 (some space) 6 2365 00011 253233 747

But on fiddle the output is : 256 236 (linebreak)(tab) 6 236 (linebreak)(tab) 5000 (linebreak)(tab) 11 253 (linebreak)(tab) 233 747

Do you think is because i have other addparser ?

Comment: Think it is because you have no new line. Try to add new line in PHP, or try to split on tab `'\t'`, or double space `'  '`.